How to knit together two bits of CSS
I am using Cornerstone Themeco Active X builder and I wanted to have a shimmering gold effect on my review stars. This was achieved by adding a class and some CSS, so them I wanted to animate this, however using the in-built animations made it go jerky and not run smooth. How do I structure my CSS so it does it all in the same class? Here are the two bits of CSS I would like to work:
Shimmer CSS
.css-selector-star-gold {

background: linear-gradient(270deg, #eede5e, #dbbb0f, #f3f2e7, #ddcd4c, #eede5e);
background-size: 1000% 1000%;

-webkit-animation: GoldGradiant 8s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: GoldGradiant 8s ease infinite;
animation: GoldGradiant 8s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes GoldGradiant {
0%{background-position:0% 11%}
50%{background-position:100% 90%}
100%{background-position:0% 11%}
}
@-moz-keyframes GoldGradiant {
0%{background-position:0% 11%}
50%{background-position:100% 90%}
100%{background-position:0% 11%}
}
@keyframes GoldGradiant {
0%{background-position:0% 11%}
50%{background-position:100% 90%}
100%{background-position:0% 11%}
}

Scale Effect On Scroll
     animation: StarScale 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
     @keyframes StaScale {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

How would I knit these together?
I tried adding the CSS together but then the animation works, and the shimmer doesn't?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Combine the HTML elements, not the CSS. Just place an element with animation A inside element with animation B.


.padding {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.css-selector-star-gold {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #eede5e, #dbbb0f, #f3f2e7, #ddcd4c, #eede5e);
  background-size: 1000% 1000%;
  -webkit-animation: GoldGradiant 8s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: GoldGradiant 8s ease infinite;
  animation: GoldGradiant 8s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes GoldGradiant {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 11%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 90%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 11%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes GoldGradiant {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 11%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 90%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 11%
  }
}

@keyframes GoldGradiant {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 11%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 90%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 11%
  }
}

.star-scale {
  animation: StarScale 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes StarScale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
<div class="padding css-selector-star-gold">
  hello world
</div>

<div class="padding star-scale">
  how are you?
</div>

<div class="star-scale">
  <div class="padding css-selector-star-gold">
    both
  </div>
</div>



